# How to have multiple color elements in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I completed a [tutorial to make a PONG game with HTML5 and JavaScript](http://blog.mailson.org/2013/02/simple-pong-game-using-html5-and-canvas/) and I was wondering how I could change the colors of the elements so each paddle is a different color and the ball is a different color. Whenever I try to color an element individually they all change colors.

Comment: Next time please include the code you tried and which didn't work. It's usually easier to pinpoint errors rather than add something from scratch.

Comment: The site had the finished product at the bottom and linked a jfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mailson/kt3Md/5/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=kt3Md)

Comment: I didn't mean the game, I meant the code you tried to color the elements on the canvas. In the linked article there is nothing colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can color any new rectangle by changing the `fillStyle` on the context. Keep in mind though, that you'll need to reset it after drawing or otherwise everything else not explicitly colored will be that color, too.

In this example I have added a parameter to the `Paddle`, which sets the color as an attribute. In the draw method it is used to set the context color and it's reset immediately after.

I'll leave the ball as a challenge to you.

```js
function Game() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    this.width = canvas.width;
    this.height = canvas.height;
    this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.context.fillStyle = "white";
    
    this.p1 = new Paddle(5, 0, "yellow");
    this.p1.y = this.height/2 - this.p1.height/2;
    this.p2 = new Paddle(this.width - 5 - 2, 0, "lime");
    this.p2.y = this.height/2 - this.p2.height/2;
}

Game.prototype.draw = function()
{
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    this.context.fillRect(this.width/2, 0, 2, this.height);
    
    this.p1.draw(this.context);
    this.p2.draw(this.context);
};
 
Game.prototype.update = function() 
{
    if (this.paused)
        return;
};


// PADDLE
function Paddle(x,y, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = 2;
    this.height = 28;
    this.score = 0;
    this.color = color
}

Paddle.prototype.draw = function(p)
{
    var oldStyle = p.fillStyle
    p.fillStyle = this.color
    p.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    p.fillStyle = oldStyle
};


// Initialize our game instance
var game = new Game();
 
function MainLoop() {
    game.update();
    game.draw();
    // Call the main loop again at a frame rate of 30fps
    setTimeout(MainLoop, 33.3333);
}
 
// Start the game execution
MainLoop();
```

```css
#game {
    background-color: #353535;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pong</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="game" width="512" height="256"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```